# How to perform calculations on csv rows and cols and create new cols using numpy and pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I have a csv that contains 12 cols and 4 rows of data.
[As seen in the img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8PXGD.png)
I would like to divide each of those values by their area of which I have created an array, and then multiply by 100 to get a % and have these values in a new column.
[Image for array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1YKqL.png)

So for example, A2, A3, A4, will all be divided by 52,600 and then x100.
My current df looks like this [dataframe](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvzT2.png)

Comment: Once you load the csv with pandas (Or numpy) you can focus on changing the dataframe.  You can then write the frame to new csv.  This gets your focus off the text file.

Comment: You could transpose your DataFrame

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I interpreted your request for a new column to be a new column for each Sub_* in your spreadsheet, since there were 12 values in your numpy array.

*Code edit: I see you wanted to do the math to the 'Baseline' column as well. So I step through each column except the first (which is "Label" and at index 0)*

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    df = pd.read_excel("d:\stack67477476.xlsx")
    area_arr = np.array([[52.6, 14.966, 7.702, 4.169, 3.71, 5.648, 6.785, 1.867, 5.268, 4.989, 1.659, 6.538]])
    for ii, col in enumerate(df.columns):
        if ii == 0:
            continue
        df[col + "_Area"] = round(df[col] / area_arr[0][ii - 1] * 100, 2)
```

This is vectorized in one dimension (the 4 rows dimension) but loops through the 12 columns dimension. The output is as follows (don't quote me on this, I may have typed your inputs incorrectly):

```
df
   Label  Baseline   Sub_A   Sub_B   Sub_C   Sub_D   Sub_E   Sub_F   Sub_G   Sub_H   Sub_I  ...  Sub_A_Area  Sub_B_Area  Sub_C_Area  Sub_D_Area  Sub_E_Area  Sub_F_Area  Sub_G_Area  Sub_H_Area  Sub_I_Area  Sub_J_Area  Sub_K_Area
0      0         0   15535    5128    8847   10784    5679   20481    8398   10012    5162  ...   103801.95    66580.11   212209.16   290673.85   100548.87   301857.04   449812.53   190053.15   103467.63   275527.43   380177.42
1      1    159506  149454  157456  155680  154327  154671  146863  150761  150446  155335  ...   998623.55  2044352.12  3734228.83  4159757.41  2738509.21  2164524.69  8075040.17  2855846.62  3113549.81  9387040.39  1963949.22
2      2    129087  111918  121515  122066  119557  123813  114746  123140  122156  125480  ...   747815.05  1577707.09  2927944.35  3222560.65  2192156.52  1691171.70  6595607.93  2318830.68  2515133.29  7608679.93  1653533.19
3      3    137562  102318  114509  124641  127442  130324  123331  130392  130715  134528  ...   683669.65  1486743.70  2989709.76  3435094.34  2307436.26  1817700.81  6984038.56  2481302.20  2696492.28  8123206.75  1881890.49
4      4     35901   26488   30836   33756   34549   34000   33269   34071   34151   35149  ...   176987.84   400363.54   809690.57   931239.89   601983.00   490331.61  1824906.27   648272.59   704529.97  2146473.78   531691.65

[5 rows x 25 columns]
```

Note that it's unclear why your numpy array is 2D, one assumes there is something deeper to that in the rest of your code. Seems it would be clearer to avoid a set of braces:

```
    area_arr = np.array([52.6, 14.966, 7.702, 4.169, 3.71, 5.648, 6.785, 1.867, 5.268, 4.989, 1.659, 6.538])
```

And simplify the divisor to just:

```
    area_arr[ii] # not area_arr[0][ii]
```

or for that matter, a simple list would be ok, since numpy isn't needed here.

Apologies if we have miscommunicated on commas and decimal points, but the code still works if you change the numbers.

Comment: Hi, This is correct yes, i do need it for every new sub, but also for the baseline, infact actually its would be baseline*52.6/100 and so on

Comment: I made the changes like you suggested,  I get the following error "invalid index to scalar variable."

Comment: If you want to divide baseline along with the subs, you'll need 13 values in your area_array instead of just 12. If you want to multiply all with the Baseline (I doubt it), then just:
    df["Area_" + cc] = round(df["Baseline"] * df["Sub_" + cc] / area_arr[0][ii] * 100, 2)

Comment: The scalar error has been fixed, is Sub_A then being divided by 52.6 or by 14? sorry this is a bit unclear to me.

Comment: Since "A" is the first column, and 52.6 is the first item in your array, then those are multiplied together. Set a breakpoint in your debugger and start to look around how it works.

Comment: oops, can't count. I originally did 11 columns. Answer updated for 12 columns.

Comment: Hello, I was wondering if if i wanted to multiply all values in row 2 for each sub by 10, in row 3 by 20, row 4 by 40 and so on would I still use a similar method, even though the array now would only have 4 values in them, but I still have 12 cols?

Comment: just multiply your result times ii*10, since ii steps up from 1 to 12 for each column.